# JavaScript - Where is the recursion?

Tags: javascript, recursion, decorator

I'm working with decorator functions and i do not want to use `bind` for passing `this` value here, instead I wanna use a wrapper function and execute the code in there.
But i faced with this error ->
`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

And here is the code:

```
let math = {
  multi(n, type) {
    if(type == 'double') {
      this.printSomething(n * 2);
    }
    else if (type == 'triple') {
      this.printSomething(n * 3);
    }
  },
  printSomething(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
};

function cachingDecorator(func) {
  let cache = new Map();

  return function(n, type) {
    if(cache.has(n))
      return cache.get(n);

    let result = func(n, type);
    cache.set(n, result);
    return result;
  };
};

math.multi = cachingDecorator((n, type) => math.multi(n, type));
math.multi(10, 'double');
```

I used Chrome Developer Tools though, but I could not fix the problem.

I know that this error ocurred because there is a recursion.
But where?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're *reassigning* `math.multi` to the caching version, then the caching version of it uses the *reassigned* value here:

```
math.multi = cachingDecorator((n, type) => math.multi(n, type));
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^
```

Instead, you need to remember and use the original:

```
const originalMulti = math.multi;
math.multi = cachingDecorator((n, type) => originalMulti.call(math, n, type));
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note that I had to use `.call(math` to ensure `this` is correct, since I copied `math.multi` to a variable; calling it directly later doesn't set `this` correctly.

Live Example:

```js
let math = {
  multi(n, type) {
    if(type == 'double') {
      this.printSomething(n * 2);
    }
    else if (type == 'triple') {
      this.printSomething(n * 3);
    }
  },
  printSomething(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
};

function cachingDecorator(func) {
  let cache = new Map();

  return function(n, type) {
    if(cache.has(n))
      return cache.get(n);

    let result = func(n, type);
    cache.set(n, result);
    return result;
  };
}
  
const originalMulti = math.multi;
math.multi = cachingDecorator((n, type) => originalMulti.call(math, n, type));

math.multi(10, 'double');
```